# add image to rmd template without creating new directory

Tags: html, r, templates, r-markdown

I am creating a custom template for rmd using https://github.com/dr-harper/example-rmd-templates. There is a method for adding a footer to the template without needing to create a directory when the template is used. It does that by calling the footer in an r code as such:

```
#' Custom HTML template
#'
#' Loads additional style and template file
#'
#' @param toc table of contents
#' @param toc_float floating of toc
#' @param toc_depth how many subsections are in toc
#' @param number_sections whether display section number

#' @param ... additional arguments provided to \@code{html_document}
#' @export
#'
html_report_format <- function(toc = TRUE,
                               toc_float = TRUE,
                               toc_depth = 2,
                               number_sections = TRUE,
                               ...) {

  # locations of resource files in the package
  pkg_resource = function(...) {
    system.file(..., package = "a")
  }

  footer = pkg_resource("rmarkdown/resources/footer.html")
  css = pkg_resource("rmarkdown/resources/dsaa_style.css")
  

  # call the base html_document function
  rmarkdown::html_document(
    toc = toc,
    toc_float = toc_float,
    toc_depth = toc_depth,
    number_sections = number_sections,
    css = css,
    includes = rmarkdown::includes(after_body = footer),
    ...
  )
}
```

I also have an image logo that I would like to be placed in the header but when I try to create a header.html that uses the image file placed in its folder, it can't access it. I saw a latex solution here: [Include Image in R Markdown Template Without Having to Create a New Directory for Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917256/include-image-in-r-markdown-template-without-having-to-create-a-new-directory-fo)

Any tips on how to do the same for html